# RecyclerView error after keyboard shown up with only if I use InputMode "AdjustPan"

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an activity with viewpager which have 5 fragment and setup with tab layout.

My view is like this.

[image]

The problem is,

1. When I setup windowSoftInputMode to **"AdjustPan"**, the
   recyclerView content **cannot be updated** again using
   **"notifydatasetchanged" and every notify** function that available.

   **But, when I use AdjustPan, user can see my edit text while typing on keyboard.**
2. When I setup windowSoftInputMode to **"AdjustResize"**, the
   recyclerView content **can be updated** again using
   **"notifydatasetchanged" and every notify** function that available.

   **But, when I use AdjustResize, my recyclerview not going back to botton, and still in pushed up position above keyboard, even if the
   keyboard has hidden**.
3. When I setup windowSoftInputMode to **"AdjustNothing"**, the
   recyclerView content **can be updated** again using
   **"notifydatasetchanged" and every notify** function that available.

   **But, when I use AdjustNothing, User cannot see the edit text while typing on keyboard.**

Please help.
Why recyclerview cannot be updated again (the adapter is updated, but the view is not) when using AdjustPan.

Comment: I am finding it very strange that a property of a view, is affecting a recycler view's ability to update its contents. Can you share a reproducible sample of this?

Comment: Can you share the code of xml and class

Comment: I'll try to create a sample for this problem.

Comment: I am experiencing the exact issue as well.  Did you find a solution?